# Copy pointer content to stack variable

Tags: c++11, pointers, memory

I have this doubt that came to my mind. Is this possible?
Consider this code:

```
int* p;
int j = 9;
p = &j;
// is it possible to declare int x and store inside 9?
// so if I do delete p; that value is stored in x
```

Thanks in advance and regards

Comment: What do you mean by "declare int x and store inside 9" ?

Comment: int x = *j; something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely read the value that `p` refers to and copy it into another `int` like this:

```
int x = *p;

// The value has been copied, j and hence *p aren't affected by changes to x:
++x;
assert(x > *p);
```

However, you definitely don't want to `delete p`, because it's not heap-allocated with `new`. Instead, `p` points to `j`, and `j` has a lifetime automatically managed by the surrounding scope.